# Why is the number of "billed" instances so much greater than the number of "active" instances?

Tags: google-app-engine

Performing load tests on my app, I noticed that the *Instances* dashboard graph shows a pretty big difference between the number of *active* and *billed* instances:

[image: screenshot]

What do *active* and *total* mean?

Also, after spending the day running load tests, here's what I see:

[image]

In the first peak, the number of billed instances pretty much matches the number of total instances. Then, on subsequent loads, the bumber of billed instances sits in between *total* and *active*.

*Update 2013-02-21*: I did another batch of load tests today, and I'm still seeing variance in where the *billed* instances stand relative to *total* and _active:

[image]

How are these numbers calculated? How should interpret them, considering that I'm trying to forecast our operational costs based on these numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems (*I believe*) that if you have F2 instance in application settings each F2 active instance is counted as 2 billing instances. If you set F4 instances it counted as 4 billing instances. And so forth.

Total instances is number of instantiated but not billed instances - kind of "gift" from Google. If there would be more requests that need more instances GAE would not need to start a new instance but would use 1 from those "non-active". When the load is raising GAE start new instances but when the load is going down GAE would keep instances for a while but would not charge you for them. But they would be shut down eventually if load did not raise back.

Comment: I did run a load test with F2 instances, so the first peak in the graph where `total == active` might very well be that.

Comment: Well, I did another batch of load tests today, all of them with F1 instances, and I am still seeing `total == billed` in one of the peaks on the chart.

Comment: What is your "Idle Instances" setting?

If it is "automatic" the total can be equal to billed.

We setup it as "1-1" and it seems our billed_count == (active_count+1)*2 <- because we use F2 instances.

Comment: Yes, idle instances is automatic. I'll play with this settings and observe the results, thanks!